# 'Constexpr' vs 'extern const'. Which has priority?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, extern, constexpr

When to use `constexpr` and when to use `extern const`?

I have a situation like:

- in header (.h):

  ```
  extern const int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS;
  ```
- in source (.cpp):

  ```
  const int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS= 99;
  ```

The files (header and source) contains just such definitions and declarations.

Is it recommanded to use just the `constexpr` in the header file and get rid of the source file, like in here?:

```
// this is in the header file. There is no cpp file any more.
constexpr int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS= 99;
```

Comment: these are orthogonal - you could always have used `const int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 99;` in the header; and then the question would be whether to change `const` to `constexpr`.  Having it the way you have it is usually only done if the value is not known at the time of the header being included

Comment: OK, and if it is in the header as you said, can it be `constexpr`, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `extern const` in the header file only tells the compiler that the variable exists and that it is not modifiable. It doesn't tell the compiler its value which means it's not a compile-time constant anymore. If it's not a compile-time constant then it can't be used for e.g. `case` or as an array size.

As said by M.M in the comment, either use

```
const int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS= 99;
```

or

```
constexpr int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS= 99;
```

directly in the header file and it will be a compile-time constant in all translation units that include the header file.

Comment: The question is now: when to use `const int` and when `constexpr int` in the header file?

Comment: In C you get linking errors, if you do plain `const int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS= 99;` in header and include it in multiple source files. Is this different in C++, or is this missing from your answer?

Comment: @user694733 yes it is different in C++; `const` variables have internal linkage unless declared with `extern` (in the definition, or in a prior declaration of the same variable)

Comment: @user694733 The question is tagged C++, not C.

Comment: @mtb That's more a question of personal preference than anything else really. The only time it is not, is if you're targeting older compilers that doesn't support C++11.

Comment: I noticed the tags, but I wasn't aware there was difference. Still, something to keep in mind when doing C compatible headers.

Comment: Note that you can also use ```constexpr const int MAX_NUMBER_ROWS = 99```. This is strictly equivalent, but I find it better since constexpr does not always indicate constness in C++14 (a constexpr member function is not const). But it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: In C++>=17 `constexpr` makes a variable `constexpr inline`, getting rid of ODR issues.

Comment: @gnzlbg Only for static data members, not namespace-scope variables (in the version that was adopted in the current working draft).

Comment: @bogdan yes, thanks, only constexpr static data members are automatically inline, namespace-scope variables need to be annotated with the inline keyword (e.g. using `constexpr inline`) to become inline variables.

Comment: There is a third alternative, used primarily to do `constexpr`'s job before there it was legal: `enum { MAX_NUMBER_ROWS = 99 };`

Answer (score 4):

`extern const` can be used if you plan to initialize the variable to a different value in the future, and don't want codes that use this variable to be recompiled. (I've never seen this need, but it might be useful in certain cases.) As others have said, the value of this variable cannot be used in constant expressions.

`constexpr` can be used when the value of the variable is know at compile-time.

Comment: a good example is version strings. if u use cmake to write current git revision into the program, it will change all the time so dont want in header

Answer (score 3):

constexpr is better if your compiler supports it.

It evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time, with better performance (less memory seek and read) and less memory costing (not exist in data section).

However some compilers don't support it, for example, visual studio 2013 or older.